# how to update the attribute value of json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
 "@id": "2",
 "@samsid": "d7058536c89b46c0b58117eff64372f7",
 "@productname": "Another paid for",
 "@downloaddate": "2013-05-28 11:37:12Z",
 "@downloadlocation":
    "2AFoGZVJpFHzspQD9UoE2C4VFYc8idiO4ebaRx4uEvtG+79DjkOUjJQjp9lJdSk54KIbFqzr",
 "@upgradeavailable": "2wECEpVJpFHS",
 "@downlaodstatus": "3QGf15VJpFFrUzr6oxwoew=="
}
```

I want to update the value of the attribute `@id` eg (`@id:2` To `@id:4`).

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want to update the actual file?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the actual file.

Comment: On the server or on the client?

Comment: You would have to do that server-side.

Comment: @vipinkatiyar You mean you have a `.json` file you want to update? Then your question is **not** a javascript problem! You'll have to use another language, most probably your backend server language. Anyway I updated my answer for this.

Comment: JavaScript **is** a backend server language.

Comment: @Quentin well yes true :) but he didn't say node.js so it was safe to assume the OP's javascript was browser code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** : Since you now mentioned you want to sore this into a file! You could still set the json into a variable like below, then set it's value. Then use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert it into a string and then write it into your file on the backend. This would really depend on how your system is designed.

---

I'm not sure why but since you have `@` in the keys for your JSON object you will have to get and set them like this:

```
//assign into a variable
var x = {
"@id": "2",
"@samsid": "d7058536c89b46c0b58117eff64372f7",
"@productname": "Another paid for",
"@downloaddate": "2013-05-28 11:37:12Z",
"@downloadlocation":
   "2AFoGZVJpFHzspQD9UoE2C4VFYc8idiO4ebaRx4uEvtG+79DjkOUjJQjp9lJdSk54KIbFqzr",
"@upgradeavailable": "2wECEpVJpFHS",
"@downlaodstatus": "3QGf15VJpFFrUzr6oxwoew=="
};
alert(x["@id"]); //shows 2
x["@id"] = 4
alert(x["@id"]);//shows 4
```

See a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jPa6n/

Answer (score 0):

if you use javascript and some libraries try something like this (I use jQuery as it is popular)

```
var a = JSON.parse('{"@id": "2","@samsid": "d7058536c89b46c0b58117eff64372f7","@productname": "Another paid for","@downloaddate": "2013-05-28 11:37:12Z","@downloadlocation": "2AFoGZVJpFHzspQD9UoE2C4VFYc8idiO4ebaRx4uEvtG+79DjkOUjJQjp9lJdSk54KIbFqzr","@upgradeavailable": "2wECEpVJpFHS","@downlaodstatus": "3QGf15VJpFFrUzr6oxwoew=="}');
a['@id'] = 4;
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```